# EFI problem on Macbook install

Tags: 14.04, live-usb, macbook, refit

I'm trying to put `ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64+mac` on a `MacBook5,2` model but right after booting into the USB, it gives the error:

```
Could not open "\EFI\BOOT\fallback.efi": 14
```

Any ideas? I'm replacing a totally messed up OS X with Linux.

Comment: I asked it here as well: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2224624&p=13026165#post13026165

Comment: How did you create the bootable device?

Comment: That message alone is not necessarily a problem; I see it on lots of systems and it causes no problems. What happens *after* this point? Does the system just hang with that message on the screen, does it launch something else and then fail, etc.?

Comment: It hangs. On the forums they suggest: "Mount your EFI partition and copy fallback.efi from the EFI\ubuntu\ folder to the EFI\BOOT\ folder" -- please add an answer with details, how to mount it, etc. if you have the knowledge.

Comment: is it along the lines of http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/ubuntu-on-macbook-air.htm#installer ? note that I want to wipe out OS X rather than dual-boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to successfully install Ubuntu on a new-ish Macbook recently (this time because I needed to return it to my employer and wanted to make sure everything is wiped out but that he could still see it functional). Used [this guide](http://www.alexvictorchan.com/2013/05/01/installing-ubuntu-13-04-on-13-macbook-pro-retina-102/).

Answer (score 0):

I used "non- mac" version Ubuntu to install Trusty Tahr on my mac. Try this

http://www.penguinsecurity.net/wp/2014/05/01/enable-wireless-in-ubuntu-on-macbook-pro/

http://www.penguinsecurity.net/wp/2014/04/28/install-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr-on-macbook-pro-retina-2013/

I also tried mac version 13.10 last year on my Retina mac and it worked as well but with some tweaks.

Comment: what tweaks did you use for the mac-optimized version? see also my comment above